# R: subsetting based on multiple conditions of the same column

Tags: r

I am trying to filter a data frame that looks like below:

```
KeyID   SQ Value.S  Course  Type    Survey.Num      
10001   A1  1      1024    Classic    1     
10002   A1  1      1024    Classic    1     
10002   A1  1      1024    Classic    2     
10002   A1  1      1024    Classic    3     
10005   A1  1      1024    Classic    1     
10005   A1  1      1024    Classic    2
```

I want to only have rows where the KeyID has values in Survey.Num of 1, 2, and 3.

So my output would look like this:

```
KeyID   SQ  Value.S Course  Type    Survey.Num  

10002   A1    1    1024    Classic  1    
10002   A1    1    1024    Classic  2
10002   A1    1    1024    Classic  3
```

I tried to use the filter() function but seems that does not work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Or a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(seq_len(3) %in% Survey.Num)], by = KeyID]

##    KeyID SQ Value.S Course    Type Survey.Num
## 1: 10002 A1       1   1024 Classic          1
## 2: 10002 A1       1   1024 Classic          2
## 3: 10002 A1       1   1024 Classic          3
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `ave` (assuming your data.frame is called `df`):

```
df[as.logical(ave(df$Survey.Num, df$KeyID, FUN = function(x) all(1:3 %in% x))),]
#  KeyID SQ Value.S Course    Type Survey.Num
#2 10002 A1       1   1024 Classic          1
#3 10002 A1       1   1024 Classic          2
#4 10002 A1       1   1024 Classic          3
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(KeyID) %>% filter(all(1:3 %in% Survey.Num))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
#Groups: KeyID
#
#  KeyID SQ Value.S Course    Type Survey.Num
#1 10002 A1       1   1024 Classic          1
#2 10002 A1       1   1024 Classic          2
#3 10002 A1       1   1024 Classic          3
```